# Catching custom exceptions raised in Flask API. All exceptions raised end up in 500 Error

Tags: python-3.x, exception, flask

I want to be able to raise validation and other exceptions in my API and catch them in a wrapped view that will return the error message as JSON.

I thought I could use something like this:

### Exception

```
class APIException(Exception):

    def __init__(self, message, status_code=406):
        super().__init__(message)
        self.status_code = status_code
```

### Catch Exceptions

```
# Todo: find a better way of handling this. Flask should have some way of handling exceptions better than this
def catch_errors(view):
    @functools.wraps(view)
    def wrapped_view(**kwargs):
        try:
            return view(**kwargs)
        except APIException as e:
            # It seems to hit here
            return json_response({'message': str(e)}, e.status_code) 
        except Exception as e:
            # But bubbles up to here and returns this
            return json_response({'message': str(e)}, 500)

    return wrapped_view
```

### Route

```
@router.route('/a-route', methods=['POST'])
@catch_errors
def get():
    return json_response(ARouteAPI().post(request.get_json()))
```

### API processing post

```
class ARouteAPI():

    def post(data):
        if not data.something:
            raise APIException("Invalid data error")
```

The problem I'm having is that whatever exception I throw it keeps bubbling up to a full `Exception` and hitting the `500` so it never returns the `APIException`.

Does anyone know why? How to fix it?

Alternatively is there a better way to handle this?

#### Update

Still having a nightmare with this.

The better way to handle it is to use the `@app.errorhandler` decorator (in my case `@router` is my blueprint name so I'm using `@router.errorhandler` instead), as suggested by @Hyunwoo.

However, no matter what exception is thrown it always ends up hitting a 500 error and I have no idea why.

I've found similar examples where debug mode causes reraising of issues, that I thought maybe causing issues but I have debug mode set to `false`

### Error Handlers

```
router = Blueprint('router', __name__)


@router.errorhandler(APIException)
def api_exception_handler(e):
    return jsonify({'message': str(e)}, e.status_code), 400

@router.errorhandler(500)
def error_handler(e):
    return jsonify({'message': str(e)}), 500 # Always hits this whatever exception is raised
```

### StackTrace

```
[2018-10-16 23:48:39,767] ERROR in app: Exception on /drone/7 [PUT]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/sarcoma/PycharmProjects/drone_squadron/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2292, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/home/sarcoma/PycharmProjects/drone_squadron/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1815, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/home/sarcoma/PycharmProjects/drone_squadron/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask_cors/extension.py", line 161, in wrapped_function
    return cors_after_request(app.make_response(f(*args, **kwargs)))
  File "/home/sarcoma/PycharmProjects/drone_squadron/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1718, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/home/sarcoma/PycharmProjects/drone_squadron/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 35, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/home/sarcoma/PycharmProjects/drone_squadron/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1813, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/home/sarcoma/PycharmProjects/drone_squadron/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1799, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/home/sarcoma/PycharmProjects/drone_squadron/drone_squadron/router.py", line 62, in wrapped_view
    return view(**kwargs)
  File "/home/sarcoma/PycharmProjects/drone_squadron/drone_squadron/router.py", line 159, in drone_detail
    return JsonRequestHandler.detail(DroneApi(), item_id)
  File "/home/sarcoma/PycharmProjects/drone_squadron/drone_squadron/request/json_request_handler.py", line 39, in detail
    return json_response(api.put(item_id, request.get_json()))
  File "/home/sarcoma/PycharmProjects/drone_squadron/drone_squadron/api/drone_api.py", line 42, in put
    raise APIException("Not enough scrap")
drone_squadron.exception.exceptions.APIException: Not enough scrap
127.0.0.1 - - [16/Oct/2018 23:48:39] "PUT /drone/7 HTTP/1.1" 500 -
```

### Error Handler Spec

Here is the output of `print(app.error_handler_spec)` as suggested by @Hyunwoo.

```
{None: {
    500: {<class 'werkzeug.exceptions.InternalServerError'>: <function error_handler at 0x7fdd0cb6ad08>}, 
    None: {
        <class 'sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError'>: <function integrity_error_handler at 0x7fdd0cb6ab70>, 
        <class 'exception.exceptions.APIException'>: <function api_exception_handler at 0x7fdd0cb6abf8>, 
        <class 'exception.exceptions.ValidationException'>: <function validation_exception_handler at 0x7fdd0cb6ac80>
}}}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I used `app.errorhandler` for handling errors in flask. (No matter whether it is custom error, or std error)

```
# IntegrityError Error handler
@app.errorhandler(IntegrityError)
def exception_handler(e):
    return jsonify({'message': e._message().split('"')[2].strip()}), 400


# Custom Error handler

# Duplicated column value
@app.errorhandler(APIException)
def exception_handler(e):
    return jsonify({'message': e.description}), 400
```

And same usage in view

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
    if something_wrong():
        raise APIException

class ARouteAPI():
    def post(data):
        if not data.something:
            raise APIException("Invalid data error")
```

Don't forget to make sure your handlers are added by flask app

```
>>> print(app.error_handler_spec)
{None: {None: {<class 'sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError'>: <function exception_handler at 0x10ae24158>,
               <class 'app.error.exc.DuplicatedValueError'>: <function exception_handler at 0x10ae54268>,
               <class 'app.error.exc.WrongSelectionError'>: <function exception_handler at 0x10ae542f0>},
        404: {<class 'werkzeug.exceptions.NotFound'>: <function exception_handler at 0x10a53c7b8>}}}
```

Comment: Looks just the ticket thanks. I'll give it a shot.

Comment: @Sarcoma And could you add your stack trace log as well? It makes much easier to investigate the problem.

Comment: Of course, I'll be on this again in a couple of hours, I'll let you know how it all goes. This looks like what I'm looking for though.

Comment: I'll cross my fingers for you. Good luck

Comment: Thanks so much for the help. You're definitely on the right track. I'm still having a problem hitting the right method though. I've updated my question and added a stack trace.

Comment: @Sarcoma Can you try to add the error handler at flask app directly rather than blueprints?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182007/discussion-between-sarcoma-and-hyunwoo).

Comment: I created a sandbox and tested a route that raises my custom exceptions and everything worked perfectly. There is something in my main program that is causing it to always throw a 500 Error. Thanks for the help it's got me on the right track. Ordinarily, this would be the correct answer, but it doesn't solve my issue in this case. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I added a message in chat, but will add here as well. Did you use flask-restful module? It has the issue related to error handler.

Comment: Thanks, for the heads up, but I'm not using it. I've given up trying to get it to work. I've looked over the stack trace and followed the code through with breakpoints. I can't work out what's wrong with it. I've written a workaround that uses an abstract Error class as a base. If an instance of it gets returned I deal the errors in a response handler that all the requests pass through anyway. It's annoying it's not working the way it should but I can do without it. Thanks for the help though.